# Check if array value is between two array values within an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing another array of numbers such as:

```
[[0, 1350], [1350, 2700], [2700, 3375]]
```

What I want to do loop though this array and check a given value is in between the two values and if it is add this to a new array.

For example say I have the value of 1320, the desired result would be this.

```
[0, 1350]
```

I am a little stuck on how to achieve this I know it requires two loops however im unsure on how to match the value to the elements.

What I have so far

```
const exampleFunction = (number: number) => {
    const numberArray = [[0, 1350], [1350, 2700], [2700, 3375]];
      const array = [];
        numberArray.map((element, index) => {
          element.map((value) => {
    // do something here?
          });
        });
}

exampleFunction(1320);
```

Comment: unsure why you would use map. Seems like find() would be what you want and you just check if greater than 0 and less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const numberArray = [[0, 1350], [1350, 2700], [2700, 3375]]
let number = 1320;
let newArray : any = []
 numberArray.forEach((numArray) => {
    if(numArray[0] <= number && numArray[1] >= number){
        newArray.push(numArray)
    }
 })

 console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Also it can also be less then first element and greater the second element

Comment: well he doesn't specify the condition @JaivBhup.

Idk when stack overflow community start bombing negative response when the questioner get his answer

Comment: @Khant i didn't mean to be rude. Sorry :)

Comment: @JaivBhup I don't mean specifically to you :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
const exampleFunction = (number) => {   
 const numberArray = [[0, 1350], [1350, 2700], [2700, 3375]]
        var num = numberArray.find((element) => {
          return (element[0]>=number && element[1]<=number) || (element[1]>=number && element[0]<=number)
        });
return num
}
console.log(exampleFunction(1320))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            const findValuesInRange = (arr1, num)=>{
              return  arr1.filter(f => f.length > 1 && (Math.min(f[0], f[1]) < num && Math.max(f[0], f[1]) >= num))
            }

            const arr1 = [[0, 1350], [1350, 2700], [2700, 3375]]

            console.log(findValuesInRange(arr1,1350))
```